# Socket.io emits not always recieved on Node.js + Redis + Heroku (multiple dynos) environment

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, socket.io, node-redis

#### Environment Context

We are running a `Node.js v0.10.25` app with `Socket.io v0.9.16` on Heroku. We are using `redis v2.6`, more specifically the Heroku add-on "redis to go", as the socket store. We currently have two dynos running.

#### Problem

The problem is that the socket connections via `xhr-polling` are sent to a socket but not always received on the same socket. An example:

- We emit a heartbeat server side.
- We do not always receive a response client side.

**Server Side Code**

```
var app = require('express')()
      , server = require('http').createServer(app)
      , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    server.listen(3001);

    var RedisStore  = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis')
    var redis       = require('redis')

    var rtg         = require("url").parse(FULL_REDIS_PATH);
    var hostname    = rtg.hostname;
    var database    = rtg.auth.split(":")[0];
    var portRedis   = rtg.port;
    var password    = rtg.auth.split(":")[1];

    var pub         = redis.createClient(portRedis, hostname)
    var sub         = redis.createClient(portRedis, hostname)
    var client      = redis.createClient(portRedis, hostname)

    pub.auth(password, function (err) { if (err) throw err; });
    sub.auth(password, function (err) { if (err) throw err; });
    client.auth(password, function (err) { if (err) throw err; });

    /** Initialize RedisStore for socket.io **/
    io.set('store', new RedisStore({
      redis    : redis
    , redisPub : pub
    , redisSub : sub
    , redisClient : client
    }));

    /** Configuration Settings for socket.io **/
    io.set('log level', 1);
    io.set('transports', ['flashsocket','xhr-polling']);
    io.set('polling duration', 10);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

        /** Associate Client ID to Socket ID **/
        client.set('client-'+client_id,socket.id, function(err){
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("User " + client_id + " socket is now... " + socket.id);
                /**
                * Retrieve the Socket ID by the User's ID
                * Send a socket.emit message based on the Socket ID retrieved from Redis.
                **/
                client.get('client-'+client_id,function(err, response){
                    socketId = response;
                    io.sockets.socket(socketId).emit('response',{user_id: client_id});
                    console.log('Retrieving User ' + client_id + ' - socket is now... ' + socket.id);
            });
        });
    });
```

**Client Side Code**

```
<script src="http://localhost:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');

        socket.on('response', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
</script>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Having the dame problem, have been working at it for a while. Have you tried socket.io-clusterhub? I tried it before redisStore and it didn't work properly, going to try it again if redisStore doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If by "We currently have two dynos running." you mean that you have two instances of your server, communicating via the redis pub/sub, then this should be what your ooking for: http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/